# How to Add/Edit records to a child table that has 3 parent tables in series

Tags: forms, record

I have 4 tables in series say tables(A to D). All tables are one-to-many. All Tables have one primary key and one foreign Key. I would like to design a form that lets me select, in succession, via a pick list, or combo box, or list box, or Text box, or query, or VBA, records in Table A to C and finally in table D which has the record I would like to edit. Below is the table structure.
[Table Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1qr0.png)

The form structure I envision is below.
[Form to Add/Edit Table_D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cukDX.png)

The idea being the final record to Add/Edit in Table_D is dependent on the path through the Tables A-C.

Thank You for your experience here.

I tried basic forms and subforms but to have a succession of 4 or more tables(4 or more subforms?) seemed cumbersome.